# Health checks fail when creating a GKE cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

When I try to create a GKE cluster it consistently fails at the last stage, when the cluster is being health checked.  Both the `gcloud` cli and the GCP console fail with:

> All cluster resources were brought up, but: only 0 nodes out of 3 have registered; this is likely due to Nodes failing to start correctly; try re-creating the cluster or contact support if that doesn't work.

The cli command used was: `gcloud container clusters create gitlab-spring --num-nodes=3`

Looking under Compute Engine I can see the VM instances and Instance Group, but I get the red exclamation indicator in Kubernetes Engine.  I'm not sure how to resolve this, as the cli command above is very basic.  I have tried recreating the cluster multiple times with the same result.

Comment: Just a follow-up in case others run into this - although this issue was reliably repeatable, I was able to address the situation by creating another GCP project and creating the cluster there.  Unsure what was broken with the old project, I had created clusters in it before.

Comment: I've tried to run yout command and it works for me. There are addional error logg from the command output? From the CLI, what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

There is a public [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#cant_create_cluster_due_to_health_check_failing) on this issue mentioning potential causes and possible solutions.

As per my understanding, and also considering the error message where it's failing after 83%. I suspect possibly automatically created firewall rules for ingress may have been either deleted or modified. If you check out [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/firewall-rules#ingress-fws) documentation, understand the purpose as this permits health checks of a NodePort Service or network endpoint group (NEG). Also, reconfigured DNS for *.gcr.io. would also result in the same time of issue. Therefore, I suggest carefully check each and every point.